# TinyMCE commands or object API?

Tags: javascript, api, tinymce

The popular TinyMCE rich text editor has an API for interacting directly with various classes, and it has a command-based API based around the 'execCommand' and 'execInstanceCommand' methods. I notice that, in some cases, the one operation can be performed via either API; so which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Functions#tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand

if you only have 1 tinyMCE on your page, then they do the same thing. if you have more than one tinyMCE instance on the page, execInstanceCommand lets you specify which editor you want to run the command on, and execCommand always runs on the currently active editor (whichever last had focus).